# C++: Reading elements from a vector, loops being skipped over

Tags: c++, loops, vector, skip

Currently trying to write a program which will ask the user for their input for a string, then read off these values via an iterator. The final step for this program would be to apply a simple caesar shift to the message before displaying it back to the user. However, since I appear to have made an error which causes the program to skip over the "for" loop (or whichever loop I use, I have tried everything from "for" to "while" to "if, else" loops). I'm relatively new to C++, so I'm hoping I simply set up my loop incorrectly, despite my best efforts.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main () {
   std::vector <std::string> vector_1;
   int c;
   int d = 0;
   int i = 0;
   std::string message;
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator it_1;

   std::cout << "Please input the message to be Caesar Shifted \n";

   while (std::cin >> message, d != 0) {
       vector_1.push_back (message);
       ++d;
   }

   std::cout << "Encrypted message is";

   for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it_1 = vector_1.begin (); it_1 != vector_1.end (); ++it_1) {

    std::cout << *it_1;
   }

return 0;
}
```

I spent a fair amount of time researching similar situations, but as far as I can tell, I've missed pitfalls others have fallen into in similar situations. Of course, being new, I could always be wrong, and so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: d=0; (std::cin >> message, d != 0) will always come out false (and will not go into the while loop). What were you trying to do here with d?

Comment: The intent had been to set up a trigger where the while loop would end upon pressing the "enter" key, though after fiddling around with nullptr's answer, I see that that the problem was lying in the first loop and not the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it_1 < vector_1.end ()
```

should be

```
it_1 != vector_1.end ()
```

and

```
while (std::cin >> message, d != 0) {
    vector_1.push_back (message);
    ++d;
}
```

should be

```
getline(std::cin, message);
std::stringstream ss(message);
std::string temp;
while (ss >> temp)
    vector_1.push_back(temp);
```

You'll want to `#include <sstream>` at the top for this to work.

Comment: The original intent had been for the program to stop taking input when the enter key was pressed, though the concept is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much, nullptr. I apologize if my question was vague, still getting used to this site a bit. However, I'm glad I was able to learn some things about the stringstream in the course of sorting this mess of mine out.